# Why is the line function in library graphics.h not executing when iterated?

Tags: c++, bgi

Here is my code. It is supposed to draw a bar chart every time it loops in main. It correctly displays the bar chart initially, but when looped, it seems like the line function does not work anymore....can anyone help me with this?
graphics library available here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/qtdy239vvr19qyi/CODE+BLOCKS+with+Graphic.h.rar
Note: I am using codeblocks 17.12

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void graph(string f){
   cleardevice();
int gd = DETECT, gm;
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "X:\\TC\\BGI");
settextstyle(BOLD_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,2);
 outtextxy(275,0, "BAR CHART");

setlinestyle(SOLID_LINE,0,2);
/* Draw X and Y Axis */
line(90,410,90,50);            //Y axis
line(90,410,1100,410);          //X axis
line(85,60,90,50);               //Arrow code last 4 line
line(95,60,90,50);
line(1095,405,1100,410);
line(1095,415,1100,410);


line(84,360 ,95, 360);
line (84, 310 ,95,310);
line (84, 260, 95, 260);
line(84, 210, 95, 210);
line(84, 160, 95, 160);
line (84, 110, 95, 110);

outtextxy(34, 350, "50");
outtextxy(34, 300, "100");
outtextxy(34, 250, "150");
outtextxy(34, 200, "200");
outtextxy(34, 150, "250");
outtextxy(34, 100, "300");

outtextxy(150, 420, "Jan");
outtextxy(225, 420, "Feb");
outtextxy(300, 420, "Mar");
outtextxy(375, 420, "April");
outtextxy(450, 420, "May");
outtextxy(525, 420, "June");
outtextxy(600, 420, "Jul");
outtextxy(675, 420, "Aug");
outtextxy(750, 420, "Sept");
outtextxy(825, 420, "Oct");
outtextxy(900, 420, "Nov");
outtextxy(975, 420, "Dec");

outtextxy(65,60,"Y");
outtextxy(1080,415,"X");
outtextxy(70,415,"O");

/* Draw bars on screen */
//setfillstyle(XHATCH_FILL, RED);
bar(150,110,200,410);
bar(225,160,275,410);
bar(300,120,350,410);
bar(375,170,425,410);
bar(450,135,500,410);

getch();
closegraph();
//cleardevice();
}

int main(){
int choice = 1;
do{
 graph();
 cout<<"Key in zero to loop:..";
 cin>>choice;
}while (choice == 0);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: initgraph() and closegraph() belong in main() so they are only done once.

Comment: @HansPassant nope this does not work. It on freezes the "Window BGI" ....

Comment: Not sure you should be mixing `getch()` with `cin`.

Comment: UPDATE: I noticed that if i change the background colour, when i loop, i can see a think black line on the window. It seems like the line thickness shrinks and the colour is set to black when we loop. WHY?

Comment: @MarkSetchell well...can you tell me why please?

Comment: `cin` is a modern C++ method of acessing the input stream, and I suspect `getch()` is an older (Windows only?) function that also manipulates the terminal/input stream... probably in an incompatible way. It's kind of like getting two hairdressers who don't know each other and aren't working together to cut your hair at the same time...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the hairdresser analogy. noted.

Comment: @MarkSetchell IIRC `getch()` was also in MS-DOS. The obvious error is as  `Hans Passant` mention in the comment.  The second is using `cout` so `Beginer001234` where do you want to output text ? BGI is switched to video mode so `cout` either does not work or switch back to text screwing your gfx again. If you have separate gfx window than you are not in MS-DOS nor BGI but in some BGI emulation and those are buggy so god knows in such case ...

Comment: @Spektre I can't even remember. I think it was about 20 years ago that anyone last used Borland graphics stuff! I think OP would do better to look at something more modern, though not sure what. SDL maybe, or SFML.

Comment: @MarkSetchell OP has most likely not a choice as schools force to use that shit (which is 99% the case in all BGI and TCPP question I saw over the few years I am here and almost all of them has un-helpfull hate comments to stop using it). I hated BGI even 20 years ago as I did much more and faster in low level on my own without any foreign engines. But I love Borland IDE's and code with it till today even professionally (of coarse not in TP7 nor TCPP anymore).